# el menu nav se queda debajo de mi seccion de imagenes, ¿como podria arreglarlo?

Tags: css, html5

[image: asi es como se ve cuando lo ejecuto]

tengo una imagen de background como portada y en el caso de que cambie la:

```
#Mundo a {
display:block;
position:relative;
```

}

se le coloca el hover que tengo para las imagenes se coloca sobre la portada

yo creo que el problema esta la etiqueta a pero no estoy seguro de si tengo mal alguna etiqueta o es algo del css

lo único que necesito es conseguir que no se pongan encima las imagenes y que el hover que tienen se quede dentro de ellas.

es mi primera vez consultando en stack overflow, estoy aprendiendo a programar asi que les pido una ayuda lo mas simple que se pueda, gracias

este es el codigo:

```css
#Mundo {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
}

#Mundo img{
    display:block;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    height: auto;
}
#Mundo a {
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    
}


/*pseudo elemento*/ 
#Mundo a::after {
    content: "";
    display:block ;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
    background-image: url(../imagenes/expandir.png);
    background-size: 80px;
    background-position: center center ;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

    transition: opacity .3s linear;
    opacity: 0;
}
#Mundo a:hover::after {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<section class="Populares">
            <h2>Lugares más Populares</h2>
            <div id="Mundo">

                <a href="imagenes/roma.jpg">
                    <img src="imagenes/roma.jpg" alt="Roma" width="340">
                </a>

                <a href="imagenes/cancun.jpg">
                    <img src="imagenes/cancun.jpg" alt="Cancun" width="340">
                </a>

                <a href="imagenes/rusia.jpg">
                    <img src="imagenes/rusia.jpg" alt="Rusia" width="340">
                </a>
                <a href="imagenes/caribe.jpg">
                    <img src="imagenes/caribe.jpg" alt="Caribe" width="340">
                </a>

                <a href="imagenes/rio.jpg">
                    <img src="imagenes/rio.jpg" alt="Rio de Janeiro" width="340">
                </a>

                <a href="imagenes/londres.jpg">
                    <img src="imagenes/londres.jpg" alt="Londres" width="340">
                </a>

                <a href="imagenes/turquia.jpg">
                    <img src="imagenes/turquia.jpg" alt="turquia" width="340">
                </a>

                <a href="imagenes/suiza.jpg">
                    <img src="imagenes/suiza.jpg" alt="Suiza" width="340">
                </a>
                <a href="imagenes/japon.jpg">
                    <img src="imagenes/japon.jpg" alt="japon" width="340">
                </a>
                <a href="imagenes/paris.jpg">
                    <img src="imagenes/paris.jpg" alt="Paris" width="510">
                </a>
                <a href="imagenes/alemania.jpg">
                    <img src="imagenes/alemania.jpg" alt="Alemania" width="510">
                </a>

            </div>
        </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes cambiar asi:

```
#Mundo {
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap:wrap;
 position: relative;
}

#Mundo img{
 display:block;
 padding-left: 10px;
 padding-top: 10px;
 Width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
}
```

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución c: Vendría genial que explicaras lo que hace tu código tanto para el OP como para personas que vean tu respuesta en el futuro.